# CodeIgniter 3 PHP 7 load view with parameters

Tags: codeigniter-3, php-7.1

My PHP version is 7.1.9 and I am working with CodeIgniter V3. I am trying to load view with a parameter (array of objects).

```
$data = 
Array
(
    [userdetail] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 4
                    [parent_id] => 2
                )

        )
)
```

My Controller code is as below:

```
$this->load->view('includes/header');
$this->load->view('includes/sidebar');
$this->load->view('userinfo', $data);
```

`$data` passed to the last view somehow stopping the above two views to load. If I remove the variable this works fine. The same code is working with PHP 5 but not working in PHP 7.

Comment: Try to [load variable](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars) before view. In example, first `$this->load->vars($data)`, then load 3 view files but without passing `$data` as second argument, so just view files load.

Comment: Thanx @Tpojka for your comment. I checked the code deeply and realized that somewhere an array is created but not initialized. I didn't receive any error message for this, but the views stopped loading. Now it is working fine.

Comment: @prabhu: following on from my last comment, I have rolled back your change here too. Out of seven changes, only one was correct, and two case issues were missed. These should not have been approved by the Review Queue, but "robo reviewing" is a bit of a problem over there.